# Plot a value also for the last (current) bar

Tags: plot, pine-script

I'm plotting a line that changes its value every month:

```
lastmonth_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", high) 
plot(lastmonth_high, color=lastmonth_high != lastmonth_high[1] ? na : color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3)
```

This way it plots no value at the actual bar.
How can I extend the line one bar to the right ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
lastmonth_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", high, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(lastmonth_high, color=lastmonth_high != lastmonth_high[1] ? na : color.blue, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested it... It plots until the last bar, but the whole line of the current month is somewhere between the value in the last month, and where it should be...

Comment: Do you mean `lastmonth_high` is high of last closed/comfirmed monthly bar?

Comment: Yes, it should simply plot the value of the last month in the following month! And I want the plot also at the current bar... the value is always the same as I see now at the second to last bar

Comment: maybe you need `lastmonth_high = security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", high[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)`

Comment: Is there a way to do this for current timeframe?